# Using Akka MicroKernel for standalone scheduler module

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka, scheduler, microkernel

We are planning to create a `scheduler` module. There is an external service which provides all the necessary tasks for the scheduler and the scheduler must invoke these tasks at intervals. Scheduler has various use cases and the scheduling would change drastically and dynamically based for data from the data store. We do not want to include this functionality as a part of the system(in `play framework`) which we are currently building  but rather have a standalone process to execute the scheduling.

Considering the above mentioned use case, would **Akka MicroKernel** serve the purpose or should we think of deploying the scheduler in some other container or application server(If so which one would guys prefer)?

Comment: Have you looked at Quartz Scheduler and ruled that out first before building your own? http://quartz-scheduler.org

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/typesafehub/akka-quartz-scheduler.